# if/while -clauses cause a critical error on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

Why I don't get this code working?

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php the_content(); ?> 
  <?php endwhile, endif; ?>
```

It works when I use only if or only while, but not nested. As far as I know, this syntax is right.I also tried changing the order of endif and endwhile in the end. Can someone help me?

Comment: Perhaps it should be `endwhile; endif;` instead of `endwhile, endif;`? I never use this syntax myself, so I'm not sure, but it seems logical.

Comment: As you can see from my post, I have tried that without a result.

Comment: Sorry, no, I didn't see in your post that you already tried to replace the comma with a semi-colon. Have you? No success?

Comment: Could you share the displayed error please ?

Comment: Sorry, I missread one comment. Semicolon is the fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        the_content();
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```